# Doctrine: atomic updates and exceptions in a loop

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

We are migrating a project from a more basic ORM to using Symfony+Doctrine. In the project we have a lot of cron jobs looking like this:

```
$rows = $someRepository->getRows();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   try {
     $db->beginTransaction(); //simple begin transaction in db
     //do some handling of data
     // Maybe load some other entities and update those
     // ...
     $db->commit();
   } catch (Throwable $t) {
      //log error 
      //clear entity cache
      $db->rollback(); //simple rollback in db
   }
}
```

When we did it this way, all changes within the try catch was atomic while it at the same time was possible to recover from an error and continue on the next $row.

In Symfony+Doctrine, I simply cannot figure out how to mimic this behaviour. The recommendation from Doctrine to handle an exception is closing the EntityManager, but how do you recover?

Answer (score 1):

The ORM does this implicitly on `flush`, so most of the time you can avoid the hassle of doing so on your own.

However, if you want clear demarcation you can still do it explicitly, in a similar manner you did so far.

More reading and examples here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html

EDIT related to the comment below:

Instead of injecting the manager, you should inject the registry.
After that on catch, you can check if the `$em->isOpen()`, and call `$registry->resetManager()` if not.

I suspect this will also reset the unit of work, so you might encounter detached entities. In that case you should do `$em->merge();`

One thing to note here is that an expection is not considered normal in doctrine, so they are closing the manager because of that. You might think that this is overcompicated - yes it is, because you are working against the philosophy here. Validate your data if you can. Read this section: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#exception-handling

As for the why: (This is not offical, just based on my knowledge) The managers internal unit of work is a stateful object. When an exception occures during a transaction that state will remain the same, but couln't be persisted to the database. If they let this go that would mean the EM would try to apply all state changes again, and would encounter the same exception again. So no point in leaving it open in the same state, a reset is needed.

Comment: That is only if no exception is thrown within the try-catch. If an error is thrown, the entityManager has to be closed, and I cannot continue the loop

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try using the Registry instead!
I unfortunately cannot avoid the exceptions entirely (various API calls that may fail somewhere along the way), but I'll limit the number to a minimum